# Admob rewarded ads server side verification

Tags: android, validation, server-side, tink

I wanted to do server-side validation for Admob rewarded video ads on my android app. For this, I followed the [instructions in the admob documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-video-ssv) but failed.

First I imported the google tink library from gradle as follows.

```
implementation 'com.google.crypto.tink:tink-android:1.3.0-rc1'
```

Then i wanted to call the RewardedAdsVerifier helper class in [google tink](https://github.com/google/tink) library as shown in the Admob documentation, in MainActivity, showing the rewarded video ads, but this clas could not be included in my system.

```
RewardedAdsVerifier verifier = new RewardedAdsVerifier.Builder()
        .fetchVerifyingPublicKeysWith(
                RewardedAdsVerifier.KEYS_DOWNLOADER_INSTANCE_PROD)
        .build();
String rewardUrl = "url";
verifier.verify(rewardUrl);
```

When I try to call the RewardedAdsVerifier class in MainActivity as above, Android studio gives me the error "Can not resolve symbol 'RewardedAdsVerifier'".

As a result of my research on server-side verification of the rewarded video ad, I couldn't find any examples or samples. I'd be more than happy to help me with how I can do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you are/were trying to do is wrong! server side verification is meant to be used on Server Side Verification!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up running mine with:

`implementation group: 'com.google.crypto.tink', name: 'apps-rewardedads', version: '1.3.0-rc1'`

as shown here:
https://jar-download.com/artifacts/com.google.crypto.tink/apps-rewardedads/1.2.0-rc4/source-code

Comment: I'm glad that this works for you. Please note that apps-rewardedads is meant for server side apps, not mobile.